# Methods to inject configuration into WAR archives?

Tags: configuration, java, jakarta-ee

I have a couple of *not so nice* Java applications. I know that those are just zip files that can be reassembled.

Is there some common tool (ant, maven tasks or somesuch) that is usually used to inject configuration?

Answer (score 0):

If I need to update a configuration file, I use the jar command to extract the file:

> jar xvf app.war WEB-INF/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml

Then, after I've updated the configuration file, I update the war:

> jar uvf app.war WEB-INF/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: This doesn't seem any better than a manual approach of unzipping replacing the file in the target an zipping. Doesn't the java world provide a standard way that one can automate?